# Custom Skin: How to get Languages into MediaWiki Sidebar?

Tags: html, mediawiki, wiki, sidebar

I have got a Wiki, with multiple languages, and a custom Skin. My Sidebar is 100% custom-made. I want to get the Language box in there. If someone uses this markup:

```
[[iwcode:Pagename]]
```

I want the link and corresponding Language name to pop up in there. How do i get it into my HTML code?

Please help me!

Best regards,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your skin class, yuou should have access to the iw links through `$this->data['language_urls']`. If you want the links in your sidebar, you can just copy the [code from the other skins](http://git.wikimedia.org/blob/mediawiki%2Fskins%2FVector.git/master/VectorTemplate.php):

```
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $this->data['language_urls'] as $key => $langLink ) {
        echo $this->makeListItem( $key, $langLink );
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: This actually works beautifully! Big thanks to you leo! I have got one more question if you got time: My Wiki is using a number of sub-domains like so:

de.[pagename].org
es.[pagename].org
en.[pagename].org

Do you think it is possible to use one database for the 3 different languages, and still use interwiki links?